# PHP IRC bot connect?

Tags: php, irc

I need a little help with an IRC bot I'm creating (very simple).

```
<?php

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$yonk = socket_connect($sock, "127.0.0.1", 6667);

$wut = socket_read($sock, 1024);
socket_write($sock, "NICK FikesPHPThingy\r\n");
socket_write($sock, "USER fikeh fikeh fikeh :Fike's PHP thang.\r\n");
socket_write($sock, "JOIN #LightSpike\r\n");

echo $wut;

while (True) {

}
?>
```

It connects and reads

```
:de.blank.net NOTICE Auth :*** Looking up your hostname...
:de.blank.net NOTICE 00AAAAAZ4 :*** Skipping host resolution (disabled by server administrator)
```

But it doesn't do anything after that. I'm creating this without any tutorials, just by myself. But I can't seem to get it working. Any ideas?

PS: Sorry for the odd variable names.

Comment: What were you expecting it to do? And why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to put the (blocking) read *inside* your infinite loop, like this:

```
while (True) {
$wut = socket_read($sock, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ); // $wut will now be a single line sent by the server
echo $wut; // Do anything with the line
}
```

This way your client will continue waiting for and handling response messages until the socket loses connection or you manually break the loop. I've added the [`PHP_NORMAL_READ`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php) parameter so the client will read only a single line at a time, this is probably way more practical for processing.

On a related note, you shouldn't join a channel right away but rather wait for the `001` response code. This ensures the server has accepted your identification and is ready to receive commands. The way you're doing it now, the `JOIN` might (and probably will) be rejected by the server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out :) Is there any documentation on response code etc? I took a quick scout of the RFC but didn't really find too much.

Comment: @Fike: RFC 1459 (partially outdated) and RFC 2812 should have most information you need, though there are unofficial extensions to the protocol not described there. RFC's can be a bit tough to chew down, though, and there are other resources on specific subjects that can come in handy. An example is [this list of response codes](http://www.mirc.net/raws/). You can find a lot more by searching 'round the web, though be aware that not everything is completely up-to-date.